# mysql add unique multi column with no check actual data

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint, unique-index

For an mysql v8.0.18 project with mariaDb 10.4.10

I would like add to my existing table an unique constraint for multi columns

```
ALTER TABLE  'new_purchasseorder' ADD UNIQUE ('created', 'fk_customer_id', 'fk_removal_id', 'fk_recipient_id')
```

but would like no check for old datas

something like that:

```
where id > 3869
```

i also tried the `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` but nor working in this case.

is it possible ?

My table looks like: [image]

Comment: You can't do this. Add it as an `INDEX`. Adding a `UNIQUE` key means that it will go back and check your data to apply that.

Comment: After all imagine the frustration in your table where results below that id would not have a `UNIQUE` key. Sit back and think thoroughly how the structure of your database is going to be based on your project's needs. To add the proper keys on tables is crucial for performance and not only that.

Answer (score 1):

Starting version 8.0.13, MySQL supports *functional key parts* - basically indexes on expression. Assuming that all 4 columns are non-nullable, you can do:

```
create unique index idx_new_purchaseorder on new_purchaseorder (
    (
        case when id > 3869 
            then concat_ws('$$', created, fk_customer_id, fk_removal_id, fk_recipient_id) 
         end
    )
)
```

The  `case` expression filters on `id` values, and generates a concatenated string that should be unique for rows that comply to the filter. I used some fancy characters to avoid "fake" duplicates.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=136eb022eba50dcce847c7b2b624f707)**

Comment: That is a nice feature https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a unique constraint as far as I know, because, as you have already discovered, such a constraint will be applied to the entire table, regardless of `id` value.  One workaround might be to use a before insert trigger, which does the assertion:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER contacts_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON new_purchasseorder FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM new_purchasseorder
           WHERE created = NEW.created AND
                 fk_customer_id = NEW.fk_customer_id AND
                 fk_removal_id = NEW.fk_removal_id AND
                 fk_recipient_id = NEW.fk_recipient_id)
THEN
    signal sqlstate '45000';
END IF;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

This insert trigger would cause any insert incoming with what your unique index defines as duplicate data to fail with an error, effectively blocking that insert.

A better long term (and easier) strategy might be to just fix your old data so that it can pass the requirements of the unique constraint.